# 12.04 64bit Installation hangs at "Copying installation logs"

Tags: 12.04, installation

When I install 12.04 64bit from CD, the installation hangs at "Copying installation logs".
I checked the ISO is correct and burned the CD at the slowest speed. I also tried to install from USB stick, same result. Also tried installing from "try ubuntu" (live CD), same result.
Any suggestions what else I might try and a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! Just reboot.. Since copying installation logs is pretty much the LAST thing the installer does system wise everything is there and setup properly so long as you didn't get any errors during the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck there because I had an endless loop in my `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command`